# Trigger task by pressing home button when on home screen

Tags: tasker, home-screen, home-button

I am trying to create a profile where I can add an extra function to my home button when on the home screen. But I can't get Tasker to react to home button press. I have tried both AutoInput and TouchTask, but none of them give any reaction. As I am using a Huawei Mate 9 Pro, which has a fingerprint scanner as a home button (no physical press, just touch/finger print), I have also tried both Fingerprint Scanner Tools and Fingerprint Quick Actions. They both work, momentarily, but after a short while the stock functionality takes over.

Does anybody know of a way to get tasker to react to home button/fingerpress press, only when on home screen, given the above limitations?